# how to encode httprequest in akka http ? ( Akka http,Scala)

Tags: scala, akka, spray

I would like to encode my httprequest (basically encoding httpentity) before sending it to server for processing.

In spray I could do something like this:

```
import spray.http.HttpHeaders.RawHeader
import spray.http.parser.HttpParser
import akka.actor._
import spray.http.{HttpEntity, HttpMethods, HttpRequest, HttpResponse}
import spray.httpx.RequestBuilding
import spray.httpx.RequestBuilding.{encode, logRequest}
import spray.httpx.encoding.{Deflate, Gzip}

object AddHeaderSpray01 extends App {

  def actorRefFactory = ActorSystem("akkaclient01")

  val myheader = RawHeader("User-Agent", "bluberry")

  val modifiedheader = RequestBuilding.addHeader(HttpParser.parseHeader(myheader).left.flatMap(_ ⇒ Right(myheader)).right.get)

  val myentity = HttpEntity("this is the request body you are currently looking at")


  val myrequest = HttpRequest(HttpMethods.GET,"www.google.com",List(),myentity)

  val modifiedrequest = modifiedheader(myrequest)


 def tempPipeline : HttpRequest => HttpRequest =
   {
      encode(Gzip)
 }
  println(tempPipeline(myrequest).toString())
}
```

What would the equivalent be in Akka Http? Or in other words, what is the equivalent for encode(encoder) in Akka Http?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think [encodeResponseWith](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/current/scala/http/routing-dsl/directives/coding-directives/encodeResponseWith.html) is what you're looking for